# How to use MutationObserver on a newly created window

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, window.open, mutation-observers

I want to use MutationObserver to track DOM changes in a window I create with `window.open`. I have the following code:

```
var newWin = window.open('/somepath');
var observerConfig = {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
    attributes: false,
    characterData: false
};
var obs = new newWin.MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if (!mutation.addedNodes) return;
        mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function(addedNode) {
            console.log(addedNode);
        });
    })
});
obs.observe(newWin.document, observerConfig);
```

I would expect to see some newly added nodes logged in the console (as I got when I tracked the original window the same way, same observer), but I get nothing. Am I missing something?

Comment: Pfft, simply observe `newWin.document`.

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried that and without waiting for the `load` event on the newly created window, It does not work. Am I missing something? (tried on Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: Try using `new newWin.MutationObserver`

Comment: @wOxxOm, I changed my code following your suggestions (you can see the edited question), and I still got no logs. When I just replace the first line with `var newWin = window;`, I can see the new node additions logged as expected, so it seems like the issue is the `window.open`.

Comment: Well, I guess it doesn't work with window.open.

Comment: Actually it DOES work with `window.open`, but only when I use the event listener as @Sébastien recommended...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same problem you would face when using JavaScript (from a script in `<head>` for instance) to modify the DOM of the current document, before the DOM has been loaded: you would be trying to access elements that do not exist in memory at this time.

You would use the `DOMContentLoaded` event to trigger a callback when the DOM has been loaded and is ready to manipulate.

Similarly, when you are trying to access the DOM of the new window, that window may not have finished loading yet.

You should wrap your `obs.observe` call in a `load` event listener:

```
newWin.addEventListener('load', function() {
    obs.observe(newWin.document.body, observerConfig);
}, true);
```

This way when you begin observing the body you are sure that it actually exists!